# Get XHR sent formdata's output as a downloadable file

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I'm doing a small HTML project of converting a doc file into another file (which is based on user preference). The website will have the user pickup the file, and choose their preferences on how the file should be processed, before sending it to a Java servlet. After processing the file, the servlet will then send the processed file as a downloadable file, which then will be automatically downloaded to the user's browser download folder.

At first, i used the HTML's form tag, with various input on it. After submitting the form, the processed file was auto-downloaded to my browser's download folder.

But then i changed the pickup file method into drag and drop, and used XMLHttpRequest to send the formdata, along with the dropped file to the servlet. The formdata was successfully sent to the servlet, and the servlet processed the file normally. But after that, the servlet didn't send the processed file to my browser as a downloadable file. I checked on the inspector, on the response under network tab, and it showed the processed file content, yet i didn't get the processed file like i would normally get using form tag method.

So i was wondering did i do something wrong in my XHR code below? I just want to get the processed file from the servlet as downloadable file, and not showing it on my page. The HTML form tag works fine and the servlet returned the processed file as auto-download file, but with XHR, the processed file was only shown in the response tab under network in the inspector, no downloadable file or whatsoever.

```
function formHandler(form) {
  var formdata = new FormData(form);
  formdata.append("inputFile", doc);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', "excelServlet", true);
  xhr.send(formdata);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i get the answer for this already.

AJAX cannot download the response from server directly like form's submit() method. =.=''' The response will be shown in the inspector's response, but user won't be able to download it.